# Understanding Session Expiration

Tags: session, web-applications

Looking at the [OWASP Session Management Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet), every time a session expires, must a user go through the same `Pre-Auth --> Auth --> ...` steps to make a new session?

For example, if a session expires and the web app requires authentication, will the user have to log back into the web app before getting a new session?

Comment: depends , you can implement a remember me function with cookies.

Comment: With the `remember me` function, how does that affect session expiration and renewal?

Comment: @Kevin well you will have two cookies both storing a unique `id`. the `id` for session references to the session data. the `remember me` references to the `userid` that is logged in. session ids normally get invalid after a certain time of inactivity (e.g. 30 min). the `remember me` info and `id` will e.g. be valid for 3 months. if no session `id` exists but a valid `remember me`  `id` then a session will be created.  but you need to take special care if you use the `remember me` functionality (if implemented the wrong way you will have a big security problem)

Comment: If my web app does not use the `remember me` functionality, upon a session's expiration, I would need to make sure to allow my user to re-authenticate so that a new session can be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are maintained with cookies.

Http is a stateless protocol. Every request to server works in isolation. No request has any information about previous request.

Say a user named `A` logs in to the site. This site works with session and sets session data for a user. Internally the server creates some value and associates with a particular user. A value `12345` is computed and associated with user `A`. The server decides to give this value's name as `sessionId`. It sends `sessionId` in the cookie and this cookie will be stored on the user's browser. Next time the user `A` makes a request this cookie will be sent to server. Server reads for cookie `sessionId`, and finds it. Then it sees with what user is the value in this cookie i.e `12345` is associated. It finds that this value is associated with user `A` and so its the user `A`, who is making the request.

Say this cookie expires, can be for various reasons. Either user deletes the cookie on his end. Or after certain days, server cleans this association between user and the session. In that case server will not be able to know who is the user making the request. And hence the entire flow of login by user, seesion generation will have to take place.

So, yes, if a session expires and the web app requires authentication, user will have to login again

Comment: To add to this, sessions are *usually* maintained in cookies, but it is also possible to use URL rewriting where the session ID is attached to all links by the container. Not much used anymore though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the user has to log in again. Also, it's important that a new session gets a new session id, as an attacker could have gained the session id. If you re-authenticate the same session id, the attacker would gain access as well. See [session fixation attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation).

Depending on the safety requirements, you might also have to implement a maximum time to life for every session. Usually an attacker would take over a session and try to keep it alive as long as possible. Expiring the session after a certain amount of time, even if it is active, is an effective way to ensure that attackers can only have access for limited time.